# Checking if there is an object in the Scene THREE.JS

Tags: three.js

is there any way to know if there is an object in the scene? is there any function like isEmpty() or something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The THREE.Scene is the root of a [scene graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph), and if `scene.children.length > 1` then it has at least one child / object in that scene. Whether any children are things that can be renderered depends on their type. Lights and Cameras affect the scene but are not rendered themselves. The easiest way to check for objects that could be rendered is to traverse the scene and search for Mesh instances:

```js
let hasMesh = false;
scene.traverse(function (object) {
  if (object.isMesh) hasMesh = true;
});

console.log(hasMesh ? 'Found meshes!' : 'No meshes.');
```

Depending on the use case you may want to check for other types, or to check properties like `object.visible` if you are showing/hiding objects dynamically.